# Unable to send mail with attached file using Javamail API

Tags: java, email, jakarta-ee, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send an email with these codes but there's an error.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.activation.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class SendEmail {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
  String host = "localhost";
  String from = "myemail@hotmail.com";
  String to = "recipientemail@hotmail.com";

  Properties properties = System.getProperties();

  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

  Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
  message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
  message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
  message.setSubject("JavaMail Attachment");

  BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

  messageBodyPart.setText("hi");

  Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
  multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

  //attachment
  messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
  String filename = "C:/Users/ME/Desktop/file.txt";
  DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
  messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
  messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
  multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

  message.setContent(multipart);

  Transport.send(message);
  System.out.println("Msg Send ....");
  }
}
```

I got a 'HTTP Status 404' error and the description is "The requested resource () is not available."
May i know why and how to solve this?
Sorry as i'm a beginner in programming and java

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please give us a stacktrace or the line where the error occurs.

Comment: it never specify which line the error occurs. It only direct to a page showing HTTP Status 404 with the description i mentioned in my question.

Comment: don't you log anything? haven't you heard of the term `exception handling`?

Comment: Add session.setDebug(true) when developing. Also, I don't understand where the HTTP error comes from! Are you sure you are running some SMTP server on your localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to do this inside a web server.

You need to somehow tell the web server how to invoke your code.  The simplest way to do so, is most likely to do this inside a JSP-page instead.